# Laravel 5 - Vendor - Class not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I am using laravel-analytics (https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics/) and have installed everything locally, works fine.

Whenever I try to upload to the server, however, I get the following error visiting the page: `Class 'LaravelAnalytics' not found` and I am trying to access it via: `use \LaravelAnalytics as Analytics;`

I am using both linux operating systems, both locally and on the server. I have also ran: `composer update` and now get: `Nothing to install or update`

I have checked the .json file and I can see the package I am trying to install is there.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^1.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "files":
        ["app/Http/helpers.php"],

        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas to what I am missing or where I am going wrong?

Comment: have you added Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsServiceProvider to your provider list?

Comment: @Tim - Yes, I have added both providers and the alisases.

Comment: @Phorce I've encountered the same problem, have you found the solution?

Comment: @riza - can you try: php artisan dump-auto load or clear-compiled - I think this worked for me

Comment: @Phorce actually, my problem is that the vendor package namespace is different with its folder naming, of course the vendor class will not be found when I used the folder naming, now it works

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar problem. Uploading the vendor/composer folder worked for me !

Comment: This should be comment i think.

Comment: Yup that did it for me too

Answer (score 1):

Being myself confronted with this problem, I first would like to thank [riza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068649/laravel-5-vendor-class-not-found/41794554#comment58779221_32068649) who put me on the path.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-analytics#install), after installed the service provider and facade, we have to do this command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider"
```

[image]

Which causes the following error : `Class 'Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider' not found`

If we see into `vendor/spatie/laravel-analytics/src`, we can see that the required classes contain **Laravel string** at the beginning of their names.

**Solution :**
So to solve this error, we need to change the call made from the `config/app.php` file :

- `providers` section. Change this :

  ```
  Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider::class,
  ```

  by :

  ```
  Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsServiceProvider::class,
  ```
- `aliases` section, change this :

  ```
  'Analytics' => Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsFacade::class,
  ```

  by :

  ```
  'Analytics' => Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsFacade::class,
  ```

Then, run again the following command, to make it work (added Laravel string too) :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsServiceProvider"
```

Then go to `config/` folder. You should see a file called `laravel-analytics.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I created own package. PHP Storm was finding class but when scripts started then status 500 was shown. The reason was simple - be sure that your package from `vendor` include in it's composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/"
        ]
    }
```

Then it will be autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Change your psr-4 to this:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "vendor\\spatie\\" : "spatie/"
}
```

hope this work for you.

Comment: I have aded this, does not work. I ran `php composer update` also.. Any ideas?

Comment: @Phorce before I have this problem with captcha plugin and laravel 5.1, I searched a lot, until I added this path to my psr-4 in composer.json: "vendor\\mews\\" : "mews/", and it's work for me.

Comment: @Phorce yes, I did. run `composer require spatie/laravel-analytics` after add that code. i hope this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the class to the aliases (or use the FQCN):

```
// config/app.php
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'LaravelAnalytics' => 'Spatie\LaravelAnalytics\LaravelAnalyticsFacade',
    ...
];
```

Comment: I have added it, that's not the problem because it works locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
"require: {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*",
    "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^1.2"**
}
```

Seems that you are using the php 5.* and that's why composer pulling the 1.2 version of the package which has different class.

I got the same problem a month ago

The read me file that you read to setup package is for 2.4 version which is for php 7.0

Just update your php 5.* to php 7.* or get the read me file of 1.2 version of package to setup package correctly

For details see my blog: [Class not found error due to php version mismatch](http://www.mchampaneri.in/2017/03/debug-errors-of-external-packages-used.html)

Comment: Same as the other answer, please edit to say that the link leads to your website

Comment: Also, please do not copy and paste the same answer to multiple questions. If a question is answerable with the exact same answer you've posted before, it's a duplicate and should be closed as one; answering it interferes with getting people answers because of this.